# Sitecore permissions removed after deployment

Tags: security, role-management, permissions

A management role was added to Sitecore and permissions were granted to the role to allow Online Comms to manage content.  The roles and accounts that were created still exist, however the permissions no longer exist.

I am guessing that deployment is overwriting permissions.

Do we need to add same permissions into lower environment, i.e DEV/SIT/UAT.

Comment: Sitecore access rights are stored on items.Have you override any item/template with the deployment? Was permissions specified for those items?

Comment: How are you deploying? Update packages via TDS?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, its always good practice to add the same permissions to all lower environment but the point here is find out why the permission no longer exists.

I think it depends on where you apply the permissions, in another words, if your deployment overrides the permissions on certain items which seems like the case.

You should always bring down the production to the lower level environment to keep the content/security settings in sync.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior as permissions are part of items. There are stored in Security section in Security field:

[image: Security field]

Switch to 'Raw values' in View Toolbar to see it like above.

It is always best practice to have same roles and permissions on all environments so all features are also testable.

If you are not planning to add roles on all environments then one mitigation could be to use Unicorn or TDS to sync Sitecore items and you will exclude 'Security' field from sync and therefore that field won't be in package and deployed. This is however highly not recommended!